# Phantom JS load a page that loads content through require JS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, automated-tests, gui-testing

I'm trying to headlessly test a website that our team built using RequireJS. Basically we load all the content dynamically via requireJS then use JS to respond to events and dynamically render content.

When I point phantom JS to our server and render a screen shot, I get a white screen, javascript is enabled because when i point it to www.enable-javascript.com I get the message "Javascript is enabled".

Here is our page HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test </title>

    <base href="/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
  <div id="page"></div>
  <script src="lib/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/es5-shim/es5-sham.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/require.js"></script>
  <script src="config/require.js"></script>
  <script>
   require(['app/boot']);
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Phantom JS:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
 
page.open("http://localhost:4567/", function (s) {
    page.render('test.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: You're probably not waiting long enough for that page to load.  What are you using for a trigger?

Comment: Maybe check out [waitfor.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) and wait for some element on the page to appear.